# jsf datatable row selection problem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I have a problem with selecting rows in the Primefaces Datatable. I use dynamic columns, so the standard row selection mechanism is not usable here, I implement checkbox selection myself.

To help, here's s simplified version of what I have in my xhtml:

```
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable id="table"
               var="result"
               value="#{tableBean.results}">

    <p:columns value="#{tableBean.columnNames}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">
      <f:facet name="header">
        #{column}
      </f:facet>

      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{colIndex==0}">
        <h:outputLabel>#{rowIndex}</h:outputLabel>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{tableBean.selectedRows[result[0]]}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </p:columns>
  </p:dataTable>
  <h:commandButton value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

And here's what I have in the managed bean to select the checkboxes:

```
package testpackage;

import java.util.*;
import javax.faces.bean.*;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TableBean
{

  private Map<String, Boolean> selectedRows = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
  List<List<String>> results = new LinkedList<List<String>>();

  public TableBean()
  {
    List<String> row1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String> row2 = new LinkedList<String>();
    row1.add("row1.ref");
    row1.add("row1.id");
    row1.add("row1.status");
    row2.add("row2.ref");
    row2.add("row2.id");
    row2.add("row2.status");
    results.add(row1);
    results.add(row2);

    //selectedRows.put("row2.ref", true);
  }

  public Map<String, Boolean> getSelectedRows()
  {
    return selectedRows;
  }

  public String submit()
  {
    List<List<String>> selectedResults = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (List<String> result : results)
    {
      if (selectedRows.get(result.get(0)) != null)
      {
        selectedResults.add(result);
        selectedRows.remove(result.get(0));
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  public List<List<String>> getResults()
  {
    return results;
  }

  public List<String> getColumnNames()
  {
    List<String> columnNames = new LinkedList<String>();
    columnNames.add("");
    columnNames.add("REF");
    columnNames.add("ID");
    columnNames.add("STATUS");
    return columnNames;
  }
}
```

The getSelectedRows method works great, but the problem is that the setSelectedRows method is never called, so I don't know which checkboxes the user has selected. Maybe I overlook something very trivial, but cannot find the solution.

Any ideas on this? I would be very glad if you helped, or give any other row selection solution for the dynamic columns.

Thx in advance,
Levi

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks you are rendering the wrong field in `selectBooleanCheckBox`.
You should be using variable or field from the `result` variable.
**My solution:**
In your situation you are rendering an object from List as a form of table row so if you want to make some changes and retrieve the status of that row then you should be using the variable from that object only.

I understand you are submitting the whole form and want to pickup all updated rows, in that case you will have to loop through the whole List and find all the rows which have been updated by checking the status in Request Handler(Action) bean.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The setter is never called for nested objects. You're the one who's responsible for creating them, not JSF. JSF just gets the nested object and then calls the setter on it (which is the `put()` method in case of a `Map`). You just need to determine the selected rows in the action method. Add an action method to the commandbutton:

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}"></h:commandButton>
```

which is definied like follows (guessing/assuming that `var="result"` is in essence an `Object[]`):

```
public String submit() {
    List<Object[]> selectedResults = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for (Object[] result : results) {
        if (selectedRows.get((String) result[0])) {
            selectedResults.add(result);
            selectedRows.remove(result[0]); // Reset.
        }
    }

    // Now selectedResults contains all selected results.
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the selectedRows still doesn't get filled with the new values by the time when the function is called. When should they get filled with the selected checkboxes?

Comment: During the update model values phase. You said yourself that the `getSelectedRows()` works great. To ensure, is it been called *before* the action method? (the `submit()` method).

Comment: Yes, the getSelectedRows() is called, but not the setSelectedRows(), so the selectedRows Map is not filled

Comment: Once again, the setter is never called for nested objects. All JSF basically does for each item is `tableBean.getSelectedRows().put(result[0], trueOrFalse)`. Add a logger or some `System.out.println(selectedRows)` inside the getter and you'll see that its content grows on each get call during the update model values phase of the form submit. If it doesn't then the problem is likely that the datamodel is not been preserved in the request of the form submit. That's an entirely different problem.

Comment: I see your point but for me the tableBean.getSelectedRows().put() is never called. I've put a breakpoint into the getSelectedRows method and this is what I see:
this is the sequence:
1. load page -> getter called once for every row
2. I manually check / uncheck checkboxes.
3. I press submit button -> getter is not called, only submit is called
4. page gets reloaded (step 1)

Comment: Then the datamodel is not been preserved. As quick test, put bean in session scope. If that works, then you have a data loading problem in the request scope.

Comment: I tried now with a SessionScoped managed bean but I have the same result

Comment: Oh? Are you doing data loading inside getter instead of bean's constructor?

Comment: BalusC I've updated my question to include the bean. It's formatted, maybe that explains my error?